# Given this Java code sample, do I have a rudimentary understanding of inner classes?

Tags: java, scope, inner-classes

I am designing a countdown timer, and found one [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4314725/java-making-time-to-decrease-to-zero-by-swing-timer). This one works great...you enter the number of seconds, and it automatically counts down for you. I modifying the code to listen for a radio button selection to set the start time. The countdown would start when the "start" button is clicked. I've got the layout worked out, but am having trouble placing the ButtonListener in the code below.

[image: My UI]

I'm *JUST* starting to work with nested classes, so some of the concepts are kinda fuzzy for me. Below, if I understand correctly, the `ActionEvent` is the countdown, which is INSIDE the `ActionListener` classk, which captures the button click. The countdown is dependent upon and cannot run independently of the button click, and all variables in the `Listener` class ALSO available to the `Event` class.

So I'm thinking that if I want to add a `Listener` and `Event` for the radio buttons, those the `Listener` would encapsulate the `Action`, which would encapsulate the code below. I've marked the class declaration for where I think they should go, but not the closing parens. I need to do some closer analysis to figure out how those are working. Is that a correct way to do things? Or is there a better way? If I declare my startTime variable as public in the radiobuttion `event`, it should follow through to the other nested classes, right?

Am I understanding all of this correctly? or am I missing some important points. This is my first project with inner classes, so please be gentle. :)

```
  public Test() {
    super("Countdown timer");
    final String startTime = "10"
    text = new JTextField(startTime, 18);
    start = new JButton("Start");
    pr = new JRadioButton("30");
    sr = new JRadioButton("15");
    lr = new JRadioButton("5");
        JPanel radioPanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(0, 1));
        radioPanel.add(pr);
        radioPanel.add(sr);
              radioPanel.add(lr);

//new button action listener here {
     // new button action event here {   

    start.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent click) {
        final long current = System.currentTimeMillis();
        try {
          final long limit = Integer.parseInt(text.getText().trim())* 1000; // X seconds
          timer = new Timer(1000, new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
              long time = System.currentTimeMillis();
              long passed = time - current;
              long remaining = limit - passed;
              if(remaining <= 0) {
                text.setText(startTime);
                timer.stop();
              } else {
                long seconds = remaining/1000;
                long minutes = seconds/60;
                long hours = minutes/60;
                text.setText(String.format("%02d:%02d:%02d remaining", hours, minutes, seconds%60));
              }
            }
            });
          timer.start();
        } catch(NumberFormatException nfe) {
          // debug/report here
          nfe.printStackTrace();
        }
      }});
    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    panel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(panel, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
    panel.add(radioPanel);
    panel.add(text);
    panel.add(start, BorderLayout.CENTER );
    add(panel);
  }
```

Comment: You might take a step back and learn how to format code before you mess with inner classes much.  What you've posted is very difficult to read.

Comment: Asking whether or not I correctly understand a concept of OO programming. Specific example: check. Answer can be based on fact (other resources I've not explored)/expertise(someone who knows this better than I)/fact(OO concepts don't change a lot): Check. Specific examples: doable, I assume...people can type, right? Check. So...yeah...that sounds like it should be closed as not constructive. WTF. I'm trying to LEARN here. I'm sorry that my learning style is one where I dive in then ask "did I do this/do I understand this right?" Is that learning style not permitted on some FAQ I missed?

Comment: @rcook - This is how I rec'd the code. Like I said, I'm just beginning with inner classes and don't know the proper conventions for formatting them...I know how to format code that doesn't include inner classes; if it's the same, I'm happy to edit the code and make it more readable.

Comment: @rcook - that would also assume that the properly indented code appearing in the edit window formats properly on SO's end. When I go in to take a look, most of the indents are just fine. Until I hit refresh in my browser, the "public" post looked fine as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code does not define any inner (= nested) classes in the typical sense of the word. You're using [Anonymous (inner) Classes](https://stackoverflow.com/q/355167/1593077). You might be interested in this SO question:

[How are Anonymous (inner) classes used in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/355167/1593077)

For information on bona-fide inner (=nested) classes, try the [relevant part](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/nested.html) of Oracle's [Java tutorials](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/). Note there are two kinds of inner classes, static and non-static, discussed in the following question here on SO:

[Java inner class and static nested class](https://stackoverflow.com/q/70324/1593077)